# rxjs: keep alive subscription besides of error

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I don't quite figure out following behavior:

```
let throw$ = Observable.throw(() => "Server error");
let testClick$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.saveButton.nativeElement, 'click')
.pipe(
    switchMap(() => throw$),
    finalize(() => console.log("finalize testClick$"))
);

let okClick$ = testClick$.pipe(
    catchError(() => Observable.of({})),
    finalize(() => console.log("finalize okClick$"))
);

let koClick$ = testClick$.pipe(
    catchError((error) => Observable.of(error)),
    finalize(() => console.log("finalize koClick$"))
);

okClick$.subscribe();
koClick$.subscribe();
```

As you can see `throw$` observable simulates an http request that returns an error.

When I click on my `saveButton`, behavior is:

```
finalize testClick$
finalize okClick$
finalize testClick$
finalize koClick$
```

The problem is that subscriptions doesn't keep alive.

I thought that catching inner raised error using `catchError`, subscription would keep alive.

Any ideas about how to keep alive my save-click observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is correct. One chain can emit only one `error` notification which makes the chain to dispose (and `finalize()` handlers are called).

If you want to chain to resubscribe you can use `retry()` operator that will automatically re-subscribe on `error` notifications`.

```
testClick$.pipe(
  retry(),
);
```

Note that `finalize()` handler will be called multiple times.